# Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL try to insert NULL value if a property not changed

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have a table with two integer columns `Opens` and `UniqueOpens`. They have a default value set to 0. I scaffolded DB with Scaffold-DBContext. I don't know why, but the default value is not set on these columns.

I create a new empty DB, applied migrations, tables were created (without default values on these columns).

I want to insert a data:

```cs
es = new EmailDeviceStatistic()
{
    Date = deviceStatisticResult.StatisticDate,
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Device = ds.Name
};

es.Opens = 0;
es.UniqueOpens = 0;

counter++;
this.Context.EmailDeviceStatistics.Add(es);
await this.Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Nothing special. As you can see I set values of `Opens` and `UniqueOpens` to 0 (default value of integer).
By saving I get an error:

> Failing row contains (4f43b05f-82a1-412b-93bb-f137c2545a52,
> 2021-02-13, Desktop, null, null).

If I set these properties to 1 (other from zero), there is no problem and a record is created. It looks like, if you don't change the property value, the provider decides that I want to insert NULL and because the column does not have a default value and is set as NOT NULL, the save fails.

So I have 2 questions:

1. why Scaffold-Context does not create a default value on a column
2. why if I don't change a default value is there a null

**EDIT:**
The `EmailDeviceStatistic` model generated by `Scaffold-Context` -

```cs
public partial class EmailDeviceStatistic
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Device { get; set; }
    public int Opens { get; set; }
    public int UniqueOpens { get; set; }
}
```

The configuration for `EmailDeviceStatistic` generated by `Scaffold-Context` -

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<EmailDeviceStatistic>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("EmailDeviceStatistic");

    entity.HasIndex(e => e.Date, "ix_emaildevicestatistic_date")
        .HasNullSortOrder(new[] { NullSortOrder.NullsLast })
        .HasSortOrder(new[] { SortOrder.Descending });

    entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Date, e.Device }, "ix_emaildevicestatistic_date_device");

    entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("uuid_generate_v1()");

    entity.Property(e => e.Date).HasColumnType("date");

    entity.Property(e => e.Device)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(150); 
});
```

Comment: Share the `EmailDeviceStatistic` model and the configuration code that `Scaffold-Context` generated for this table.

Comment: Please Edit your post and add the codes in the post, not in comment section.

Comment: @atiyar sorry :) I added the code, but there is nothing special

Comment: 1) EF does not need that information in its model configuration code, because in .NET default value for `int` type `0`, and if you don't set a value for an `int` type property, a value of `0` will be set for that column anyway.  
2) If you created a migration without making any changes to the code generated by `Scaffold-Context`, then that error shouldn't occur. I tested in SQL Server. It might be something related to the `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` package.

Comment: @atiyarof course I know how EF works and that the default value of int is 0. therefore I expected, that EF puts 0 to the SQL command, but how you can see there is null.

Comment: @atiyar I described this issue in the GitHub https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1758

Comment: 1) I just tried to explain why the default values are not set on these columns in config code, 2) Your expectation totally make sense. As I said - the "_error shouldn't occur. I tested in SQL Server._" and It works as expected, 3) I just gave a +1 on your post GitHub post :)